# Build dynamic menu items in custom TimyMCE button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE react component to load an editor. I am trying to add a custom menu item, and have gotten one of the documentation examples working fine. However, I am trying to dynamically build the menu items in this custom menu button. Here is the working example:

```
<Editor
            apiKey='123'
            onChange={(e) => this.handleDirty(e)}
            onInit={(evt, editor) => this.editorRef.current = editor}
            initialValue={this.renderInputValue('body')}
            init={{
                height: 600,
                menubar: true,
                plugins: [
                    'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
                    'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
                    'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'code', 'help', 'wordcount'
                ],
                toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | ' +
                    'bold italic forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
                    'removeformat | insertvarbutton help',
                setup: function (editor) {
                    /* Menu items are recreated when the menu is closed and opened, so we need
                       a variable to store the toggle menu item state. */
                    var toggleState = false;

                    /* example, adding a toolbar menu button */
                    editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('insertvarbutton', {
                        text: 'Insert Variable',
                        fetch: function (callback) {
                            let test = []
                            let items = [
                                {
                                    type: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'Menu item 1',
                                    onAction: function () {
                                        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<em>You clicked menu item 1!</em>');
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    type: 'nestedmenuitem',
                                    text: 'Menu item 2',
                                    icon: 'user',
                                    getSubmenuItems: function () {
                                        return [
                                            {
                                                type: 'menuitem',
                                                text: 'Sub menu item 1',
                                                icon: 'unlock',
                                                onAction: function () {
                                                    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<em>You clicked Sub menu item 1!</em>');
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                type: 'menuitem',
                                                text: 'Sub menu item 2',
                                                icon: 'lock',
                                                onAction: function () {
                                                    editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<em>You clicked Sub menu item 2!</em>');
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ];
                                    }
                                }
                            ];
                            callback(items);
                        }
                    });

                },
                content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
            }}
        />
```

I am looking at the documentation and it sounds like I can use the fetch function to build the items each time the custom dropdown menu is opened. Front end is not my strong suit, so I'm probably missing something simple here, but i'm just wanting to provide a function to the fetch so that I can dynamically build the menu. Something like this:

```
                setup: function (editor) {
                    /* Menu items are recreated when the menu is closed and opened, so we need
                       a variable to store the toggle menu item state. */
                    var toggleState = false;

                    /* example, adding a toolbar menu button */
                    editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('insertvarbutton', {
                        text: 'Insert Variable',
                        fetch: this.buildCustomEditorButtons(editor)
                    });

                },
```

notice the `fetch: this.myFunctionThatReturnsItems(editor)` section.

Then my function to build the menu items looks something like this:

```
    buildCustomEditorButtons(editor) {
    let test = []
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.templateVars.system_vars)) {
        test << {
            type: "nestedmenuitem",
            text: key,
            getSubmenuItems: function () {
                value.map((i) => {
                    return {
                        type: 'menuitem',
                        text: i.name,
                        onAction: function () {
                            editor.insertContent(i.value);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    return(test)
}
```

I've tried a number of different syntax there. I've seen a couple of examples that are closish to what i'm trying to do, but they all use a const inside the setup function, not an external function. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured the problem out. `this` was out of scope inside the anonymous function. So I was able to fix it by defining `_this = this` above the editor init, then doing:

```
fetch: function (callback) {
                            let items = _this.buildCustomEditorButtons(editor);
                            callback(items);
                        }
```

I believe I can also use arrow notation like `() =>`  or something along these lines in the function declaration.